# Get group list for given user account

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Please I need to retrieve group list for a given user account, the only solution I found is to use [google-admin-sdk](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/list), but unfortuantly it needs to have an admin account, but for me I have only a free gmail.com account, when i use it I get `Not Authorized to access this resource/api`.
So my question now is :

- Is it mandatory to have an admin account for a specific domain to use this
  api.
- Can I get an admin account from my gmail.com account.
  Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need to have an admin account. And you would need to have Workspace accounts for that. https://workspace.google.com/. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: thank you for your quick reply @lamblichus, I see , let's say that we have a workspace admin account, can we give the right to get list group members for user in the same domain but without being administrator ? thank you

Comment: Yes, if you are a domain admin, you can confer `Groups` privilege to a regular user without them being a domain admin, and then they will be able to list group members. https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251?hl=en#zippy=%2Cgroups.

Comment: Thank you @lamblichus, appreciate your help.

Comment: Cool, of course  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

In order to use [groups.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/list) (part of [Google Workspace Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk)), you need to have a [Google Workspace](https://workspace.google.com/) account.

Any Workspace account in your domain that has been granted `Group` privileges can list groups in that domain using this API.

#### Reference:

- [Group privileges](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251?hl=en&ref_topic=9832445)